# document clustering by semantic similarity based EMD(earth mover distance)

Tags: text-mining, clustering

I want the text-based semantic clustering EMD do.
Is there a better way of using LDA to detect topics in text, there are so provide better results?
I'm going to do my EMD on discovery topics.
Thanks

Comment: re: "Is there a better way of using LDA to detect topics in text, there are so provide better results?" 

Could you clarify your question a bit? What do you mean by "better?"

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you should read the article [From Word Embeddings To Document Distances](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf). In this article, authors implement WMD - Word Mover's Distance and after that solve classification task. Instead of classification methods, see clustering methods that are applicable to your data. If your objects aren't described as points in space, see algorithms for that require only distance (eg. [k-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids), [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN)). Otherwise, your choice is wider, you can use classical algorithms, [K-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) for instance. Also, I recommend to read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81481/why-does-k-means-clustering-algorithm-use-only-euclidean-distance-metric) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32925/perform-k-means-or-its-close-kin-clustering-with-only-a-distance-matrix-not-p) issues, that are related to this problem.